# resolution problem with nvidia craphic card GT540M

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

i upgraded ubuntu to 12.04, i have lenovo ideapad with GT540M 2GB graphic card, 2nd gen i5 processor.
when i installed nvidia drivers, screen resolution changed to 640X480, can nvidia drivers be installed, coz i have tried many ways and took help of almost all discussions on this site. is this problem of optimus or anything else. please help me out.

Comment: Have you enabled any additional drivers via Jockey (The additional drivers GUI)?

Comment: i am same anuj.
i did the same thing as u said, but after removing the nvidia proprietary drivers i reebooted it, and after i entered the first command from bumblebe project page its showing this error. "pycurl.error: (6, "Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net'")"
what to do now.

Comment: Check your Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hybrid graphics and installed the nvidia-drivers without bumblebee you are in for a lot of touble! Just kidding...

Remove the nvidia proprietary drivers either by `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nvidia*`  or through synaptic (if you have it installed) then reboot.

Now:

follow the instructions on [this wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) about how to properly install bublebee with nvidia drivers and enjoy your laptop to its fulliest!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still getting low resolution you should delete `Xorg.conf` file

```
$ sudo rm /etc/X11/Xorg.conf
```

While following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) procedure it is better you should not start `X server`

Instead login through text mode.
To login to text mode use the following

```
$ sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`
and `$ sudo update-grub`

After installing `nvidia-current and bumblebee`, revert the changes in `/etc/default/grub` to login into graphical mode.